# Beamer/Latex, is there a way to put a theorem in an "itemize", and hide the bullet?

Tags: beamer, itemize

```
\frametitle{Intro LDP: Brownian Motion 2}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Let $(W_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ a Brownian Motion.
\item<2-> For $\varepsilon >0$ let $\mu_\varepsilon $ the PFM of $\varepsilon W$ on $\mathcal C_0[0,T]$
\item<3-> \begin{theo}[Schiler]
$(\mu_\varepsilon )_{\varepsilon >0}$ satisfies LDP with rate function \begin{equation}I_W(\varphi )=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}\int_0^T \dot \varphi ^2&\varphi \in H_0^1[0,T]\\+\infty &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{equation}
\end{theo}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

I get this [image]

And I don't like the 3rd bullet under the theorem. Is there a way to hide it ? An other solution was to put the theorem out \begin{itemize}\end{itemize}, but then, it won't appear after the first step (I want to show the bullet step by step).

Comment: Perhaps you can put your theorem out of itemize and add a `\pause` in front of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possibilites, both resulting in the following output. (Since there was no MWE give, I had to make some not so accurate assumptions about the code.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Intro LDP: Brownian Motion 2}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Let $(W_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ a Brownian Motion.
\item<2-> For $\varepsilon >0$ let $\mu_\varepsilon $ the PFM of $\varepsilon W$ on $\mathcal C_0[0,T]$
\item[]<3-> \begin{theorem}[Schiler]
$(\mu_\varepsilon )_{\varepsilon >0}$ satisfies LDP with rate function \begin{equation}I_W(\varphi )=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}\int_0^T \dot \varphi ^2&\varphi \in H_0^1[0,T]\\+\infty &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{equation}
\end{theorem}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}




\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Intro LDP: Brownian Motion 2}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Let $(W_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ a Brownian Motion.
\item<2-> For $\varepsilon >0$ let $\mu_\varepsilon $ the PFM of $\varepsilon W$ on $\mathcal C_0[0,T]$\pause
\end{itemize}
\pause
\begin{theorem}[Schiler]
$(\mu_\varepsilon )_{\varepsilon >0}$ satisfies LDP with rate function \begin{equation}I_W(\varphi )=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}\int_0^T \dot \varphi ^2&\varphi \in H_0^1[0,T]\\+\infty &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{equation}
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```